# How can I insert variable into formula in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, formula

Can anyone solve this?

```
Sub test

Dim i as integer

For I = 1 to 10
   ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Formula = "=Sum(E15,&i&)"
Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: you need to take the `i` out of the `"`. But what are you trying to `Sum` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

your actual goal is unclear

you may want to start form this code

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 10
       cells(i, 4).Formula = "=Sum(E" & i & ":E15)"
    Next
End Sub
```

and adjust it to your needs, knowing that:

- it currently writes in cells "D1:D10"

  since `cells(i, 4)`  references a cell in 4th column (i.e.: column "D") 4 and `i` row, and we're inside a loop where `i` is looping through 1 to 10

  so if:

  - you want to reference a different column then just change `4` to the proper column index
  - you want to reference a different row then just change `i` to the proper row index (may be some `i+2` if you need to iterate through 1 to 10 but start writing from row `3`)
- the `formula` written in those cells is:

  `=SUM(E1:E15)` in D1,

  `=SUM(E2:E15)` in D2,

  ....

  `=SUM(E10:E15)` in D10.

  so just change `"=Sum(E" & i & ":E15)"` to your actual needs

Comment: Actually I did try on this  "=Sum(E" & i & ":E15)" 
but I forgot to leave a space between the ampersand,& and "i"
That's the reason I couldn't have this code work><

Comment: fine. then you may want to mark answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You're close, trying to use ampersands (`&`) to concatenate strings.

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Formula = "=Sum(E15," & i & ")"
```

Use the ampersands between strings to merge them, not inside strings.

Comment: What is the purpose of the formula `=SUM(E15,1)` ?

Comment: Thanks, if it's the accepted answer then please mark it so... @ShaiRado, I agree it's unclear what the OP is trying to achieve, but this is the solution to their specific problem :)