# Variable Workbook Name in Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code that takes a variable workbook name (declared earlier) and inputs it into a formula that will be pasted into a cell.

I have it to the point where the formula works if I just write the workbook in, and I have the variable declaration with the workbook path working okay, I just can't figure out the formatting to drop the variable into the formula code.

```
'''Spreadsheet opening and variable declaration

strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Select an updated Inventory Report", _
FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xls* (*.xls*),")

If strFileToOpen = False Then

    'Displaying a message if file not choosedn in the above step
    MsgBox "No file selected.", vbExclamation, "Sorry!"

    'And existing from the procedure
    Exit Sub
Else

End If

Workbooks.Open Filename:=strFileToOpen



Set InvRpt = ActiveWorkbook

InvRptName = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

Set InvSht = InvRpt.Worksheets("ALL")

'''Formula insert

ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(GETPIVOTDATA(""Sec QTY Sum"", 'InvRptName'!$A$4,""Alias"",""" & y & """)),0,GETPIVOTDATA(""Sec QTY Sum"", 'InvRptName'!$A$4,""Alias"",""" & y & """))"
```

The end result would be for this code to work exactly like this, but with a variable instead of the workbook/sheet name:

```
 ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(GETPIVOTDATA(""Sec QTY Sum"", '[8-14-19 AM INVENTORY.xls]Sheet2'!$A$4,""Alias"",""" & y & """)),0,GETPIVOTDATA(""Sec QTY Sum"", '[8-14-19 AM INVENTORY.xls]Sheet2'!$A$4,""Alias"",""" & y & """))"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I insert variable into formula in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42503316/how-can-i-insert-variable-into-formula-in-vba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always helps to place a Break Point into the line where you are having issues then use the Intermediate Window to figure out where it is going wrong. For example;

1. Place a Break Point at the last line where you have ActiveCell.Formula =
2. Run the code
3. In the Intermediate Window type `?"=IF(ISERROR(GETPIVOTDATA(""Sec QTY Sum"", 'InvRptName'!$A$4,""Alias"",""" & y & """)),0,GETPIVOTDATA(""Sec QTY Sum"", 'InvRptName'!$A$4,""Alias"",""" & y & """))"`
4. Note; The ? instructs the Intermediate Window that you want to see a return value.
5. If it compiles ok you should see a resulting string, see if it looks as you expected. I'd guess your result will include the text **'InvRptName'** where you are expecting **'[8-14-19 AM INVENTORY.xls]Sheet2'**.

To get **'[8-14-19 AM INVENTORY.xls]Sheet2'!$A$4** try using;

```
?"'[" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "]" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!$A$4"
```

Another couple hot tips;

1. Use `Debug.Print "add your messages here or a variable " & InvRptName` within your code to output debug messages.
2. Use the Intermediate Widow to fix variables during execution `InvRptName = "'[" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "]" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!$A$4"` notice I excluded the ? this time.

Comment: Thank you! Separating it out into the workbook name and active sheet name to get the right formatting was exactly what I needed.