# excel range vba

Tags: excel, vba, range

how to make below formula to work in VBA

#### lastrowA and lastrowCheck is the range i want to use

```
Worksheets("Investigate").Range("F & lastrowA,F" & lastrowCheck).Formula = "=SUMIFS(L$1:L$12,F$1:F$12,A&lastrowA,G$1:G$12,B&lastrowA,E$1:E$12,C&lastrowA,K$1:K$12,D&lastrowA)"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42503316/how-can-i-insert-variable-into-formula-in-vba

Comment: For starters; your range is formatted incorrectly, should be something like this, e.g. `,Range("F" & arownumber & ":" & "F" & lastRow)` to select a valid range. Also, you seem to be using two last row variables `lastrowA` and `lastrowCheck`, you need to clarify what these two variables are.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Investigate").Range("F" & lastrowA & ":F" & lastrowCheck)
    .Formula = "=SUMIFS(L$1:L$12,F$1:F$12,A" & lastrowA & ",G$1:G$12,B" & lastrowA & ",E$1:E$12,C" & lastrowA & ",K$1:K$12,D" & lastrowA & ")"
End With
```